# Display only country and continent labels on HERE Basemap Tiles

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm using HERE api to get a tile layer with labels only. I'm doing it using the code from the example (https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/example-labeltile.html):

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
var HERE_labels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.{base}.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/{type}/{mapID}/normal.day/{z}/{x}/{y}/{size}/{format}?app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}&lg={language}', {
  subdomains: '1234',
  mapID: 'newest',
  app_id: '{app_id}',
  app_code: '{app_code}',
  base: 'base',
  type: 'labeltile',
  language: 'eng',
  format: 'png8',
  size: '256'
});

HERE_labels.addTo(mymap);
```

You can see the working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/crc3vgrr/

However, what I want, is to remove all labels except the country and continent's name (I don't need cities or road signs on my map).
I see that HERE has a powerful API, but I haven't found any options that allow me to do that.

Is that achievable at all?

Or maybe there are some other tile providers that have multilingual labels-only tiles?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that cannot be done because the tiles are pre-rendered pngs on the server and cached.

Hopefully we will have a vector based solution soon also for the web!